# Filter a String

Tags: c#, string, filtering

I want to make sure a string has only characters in this range

[a-z] && [A-Z] && [0-9] && [-]

so all letters and numbers plus the hyphen. 
I tried this...

C# App:

```
        char[] filteredChars = { ',', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '_', '+', '=', '{', '}', '[', ']', ':', ';', '"', '\'', '?', '/', '.', '<', '>', '\\', '|' };
        string s = str.TrimStart(filteredChars);
```

This TrimStart() only seems to work with letters no otehr characters like $ % etc

Did I implement it wrong?
Is there a better way to do it?

I just want to avoid looping through each string's index checking because there will be a lot of strings to do...

Thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: You should check that the input is valid rather than what it shouldn't take. Use Regex to check your string.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This seems like a perfectly valid reason to use a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expresions.info).

```
bool stringIsValid = Regex.IsMatch(inputString, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9\-]*?$");
```

In response to miguel's comment, you could do this to remove all unwanted characters:

```
string cleanString = Regex.Replace(inputString, @"[^a-zA-Z0-9\-]", "");
```

Note that the caret (`^`) is now placed *inside* the character class, thus negating it (matching any non-allowed character).

Comment: A little disclaimer: I just made the pattern up from the top of my head, so it might not be exactly what you're after. You'll be able to find the information you need to construct your ideal pattern if you follow the link.

Comment: You need to put an @ symbol infront of the string so it doesn't try to escape the - : Regex.Replace(s, @"[^A-z0-9\-]", "");

Comment: Awesome exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: What is the ? doing in the expression??

Comment: Quote from regular-expressions.info/reference.html: ? "Makes the preceding item optional. Greedy, so the optional item is included in the match if possible." Now that I think about it, you might not want that in this specific pattern, but I think it'll work with or without...

Comment: It would be wise to pre-compile the regex into a private static variable.

Comment: It would. However, this was not intended as the final solution, but merely as a pointer in the right direction =)

Answer (score 17):

Here's a fun way to do it with LINQ - no ugly loops, no complicated RegEx:

```
private string GetGoodString(string input)
{
   var allowedChars = 
      Enumerable.Range('0', 10).Concat(
      Enumerable.Range('A', 26)).Concat(
      Enumerable.Range('a', 26)).Concat(
      Enumerable.Range('-', 1));

   var goodChars = input.Where(c => allowedChars.Contains(c));
   return new string(goodChars.ToArray());
}
```

Feed it "Hello, world? 123!" and it will return "Helloworld123".

Comment: I must say I like this, just because you're avoiding RegExes =) +1!

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use replace instead? Trimstart will only remove the leading characters in your list...

Comment: just write a loop to scan and remove then

Answer (score 3):

Try the following

```
public bool isStringValid(string input) {
  if ( null == input ) { 
    throw new ArgumentNullException("input");
  }
  return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(input, "^[A-Za-z0-9\-]*$");
}
```

Comment: Or you could do this: return Regex.Replace(input ?? string.Empty, @"[^A-z0-9\-]", "");

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure that with a bit more time you can come up wiht something better, but this will give you a good idea:

```
public string NumberOrLetterOnly(string s)
{
    string rtn = s;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!char.IsLetterOrDigit(rtn[i]) && rtn[i] != '-')
        {
            rtn = rtn.Replace(rtn[i].ToString(), " ");
        }
    }
    return rtn.Replace(" ", "");
}
```

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that he didn't want loops. Besides the regex solution looks better anyway.

I won't delete my post though, because some of those methods still might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I have tested these two solutions in Linqpad 5. The benefit of these is that they can be used not only for integers, but also decimals / floats with a number decimal separator, which is culture dependent. For example, in Norway we use the comma as the decimal separator, whereas in the US, the dot is used. The comma is used there as a thousands separator. Anyways, first the Linq version and then the Regex version. The most terse bit is accessing the Thread's static property for number separator, but you can compress this a bit using static at the top of the code, or better - put such functionality into C# extension methods, preferably having overloads with arbitrary Regex patterns.

```
string crappyNumber = @"40430dfkZZZdfldslkggh430FDFLDEFllll340-DIALNOWFORCHRISTSAKE.,CAKE-FORFIRSTDIAL920932903209032093294faøj##R#KKL##K";

string.Join("", crappyNumber.Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)|| c.ToString() == Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator)).Dump();

new String(crappyNumber.Where(c => new Regex($"[\\d]+{Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator}\\d+").IsMatch(c.ToString())).ToArray()).Dump();
```

Note to the code above, the Dump() method dumps the results to Linqpad. Your code will of course skip this very last part. Also note that we got it down to a one liner, but it is a bit verbose still and can be put into C# extension methods as suggested.

Also, instead of string.join, newing a new String object is more compact syntax and less error prone.

We got a crappy number as input, but we managed to get our number in the end! And it is Culture aware in C#!